# WM_EX_COMPOSITED without double-buffering

Tags: c++, c, winapi, doublebuffered, double-buffering

I am trying to implement double-buffering in a Win32 application, so I need the controls of a window to be painted from the backmost-control to the frontmost. As I understand it, `WM_EX_COMPOSITED` does this, but it also does double-buffering itself<sup>1</sup>. How can I get windows to be painted from bottom to top like `WS_EX_COMPOSITED` without getting the double buffering along with it?

---

I am not using `WM_EX_COMPOSITED` for double buffering because I think I can do a better job manually and not have flicker with DWM, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`WS_EX_TRANSPARENT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa251511%28v=vs.60%29.aspx) extended window style to make the top-level window paint last.

Comment: I thought I had tried this but I guess I just didn't do it right, thanks.